# How to insert data in Postgresql without having to indicate the primary key column?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-insert, auto-increment

In MySQL, I can easily insert a data without having to write the column names. meaning, I can set primary key as null and the engine auto recognizes it that am trying to insert a new record
e.g

```
INSERT INTO person VALUES (null, 'john','doe');
```

Then in database, it will appear like this,

```
1 | John | Doe
```

But having said that, it's for MySQL, what about for PostgreSQL? Is there such shortcut as well?

Because when I tried this in **PostgreSQL**:

```
INSERT INTO person VALUES (null, 'john','doe');
```

I was getting an error `null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`

Comment: A primary key column cannot have NULL values. Any attempt to insert or update NULL to primary key columns will result in an error.

Comment: Obviously trying to store NULL in a column defined as NOT NULL is going to result in an error. Why would you expected anything else? And you should **really** specify the column names. It makes your code much more robust.

Answer (score 4):

You can insert data for **`SERIAL` column** with **`DEFAULT`** as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO person VALUES 
(DEFAULT, 'John', 'Smith'),
(DEFAULT, 'Lisa', 'Miller');
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the MySql approach you want, I ALWAYS specify my columns. It isolates me from database changes that do not effect the specific process. It is also generally considered a better practice.  However, you can get what you want, just not with the specifics you' are using. Try:

```
insert into person values(DEFAULT,'john','doe');
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgresql, if you declared id as `serial primary key` then you can do like this:

```
INSERT INTO person(fname,lname) VALUES ('john','doe');
```

In this case **id** is auto increment.

In case id is only integer then you should do like this:

```
INSERT INTO person VALUES (1,'john','doe');
```

In both cases result is same:

```
---------------------------------------------------
id        |   fname      |     lname
-----------------------------------------------
1         |    john      |     doe
```

Comment: you saw my example right? is there a way not to indicate the table column names ?, because in MySQL i can straight away insert values without indicating the table column names

Comment: what is the data type of ```id``` column in your table?

Comment: bigserial not null primary key

Comment: In case ```id``` is bigserial, then you should write column names except ```id```. Otherwise it gives an error.

Comment: In addition if your column is primary key you cannot add null value. Because primary key also means not null constraint in Postgresql

Comment: I see, so Postgresql cannot handle it automatically...in MySQL it can handle automatically...if you pass null, it means, it's a sequence since it was defined as primary key